# Skip Serializing the the Property Name for a JSON Object using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the below simple class

```
class MyType {
    string JsonData { get; set;}

    string OtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

where `JsonData` contains formatted JSON that I want to plug into the serialized class output:

```
"Prop1":"Value1",
"Prop2":"Value2",
"Prop3":"Value3"
```

and I want to have it serialized as

```
{
    <JsonData>,
    "OtherProperty": ""
}
```

I have tried using a custom `JsonConverter` for that field, but I cannot find a way to remove the serialization of the property name:

```
{
    "JsonData": <JsonData>,
    "OtherProperty": ""
}
```

So basically I just need to have `"JsonData":` removed from the output (preferably without using `string.Replace()`)

Comment: Not an answer, but what you are trying to serialize is not valid JSON.  You can only serialize values without a property name in an array.  You are attempting to mix-and-match array properties with regular properties and this creates invalid JSON.

Comment: It sounds like he just wants to move the licit JSON in the sub-object up a level. That's not so hard, actually... You can create a new dynamic object, set its fields to be the parsed value of `JsonData`, then set its `OtherProperty` field and serialize that.

Comment: @a-p correct, but I need to also avoid the deserialization of `JsonData`

Comment: @the_void either you parse it or you do string manipulations on it, which would essentially be writing a special use ghetto parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a custom `JsonConverter`, but the converter has to be made to handle the whole `MyType` class as opposed to just the `JsonData` property.  As you've seen, there is no way to omit the property name from within a converter that handles just the property.

Here is how I might write the converter:

```
class MyTypeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(MyType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        MyType mt = (MyType)value;
        JObject jo = new JObject();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mt.JsonData))
        {
            // JsonData is assumed to contain pre-formatted, comma-separated, JSON properties
            jo.Add(JObject.Parse("{" + mt.JsonData + "}").Properties());
        }

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(MyType).GetProperties()
                 .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.Name != "JsonData"))
        {
            object val = prop.GetValue(mt, null);
            jo.Add(prop.Name, val != null ? JToken.FromObject(val, serializer) : JValue.CreateNull());
        }

        jo.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the converter, just annotate your class with a `[JsonConverter]` attribute like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyTypeConverter))]
class MyType
{
    ...
}
```

Demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bu0NgC

---

Having presented the above, I should point out that this might not be the best solution, depending on where the pre-formatted JSON properties are coming from.  If they are coming from a third party out of your control, then the design you have along with the converter is probably adequate.  However, if you are creating the pre-formatted JSON properties yourself somewhere along the line as a way of having dynamic properties in your `MyType` class, then there is *definitely* a better way to do it.

Instead of using a string, you can declare `JsonData` as a `Dictionary<string, object>` and mark it with the special `[JsonExtensionData]` attribute:

```
class MyType 
{
    public MyType()
    {
        JsonData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> JsonData { get; set;}

    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then, just add your dynamic properties to the dictionary as key-value pairs:

```
MyType mt = new MyType();
mt.JsonData.Add("Prop1", "Value1");
...
```

When you serialize `MyType`, the dictionary KVPs will be automatically added as properties of the JSON object just like `OtherProperty`.  No converter needed!

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/f8gCVA

Comment: The `JsonExtensionData` trick is pretty neat! The JSON data I'm using is pre-cooked and just wanted a way to avoid deserialization, for perf reasons, so class converter using `WriteRawData()` will do the job!